# Oracle integer to number conversion

Tags: oracle, datatypes

According to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i54335), creating a table with a column of ANSI type `INT`, Oracle will convert it to `NUMBER(38)`.  According to the same document, `NUMBER(38)` is supposed to be a `NUMBER` with a precision of 38 and a scale of 0. But in practice, I am seeing a `NUMBER` with data_precision set to `NULL` and a data_length set to 22.

```
SQL> create table ltheisen.silly ( id int );

Table created.

SQL> select substr(data_type,1,10), data_length, data_scale, data_precision from
 all_tab_columns where owner='LTHEISEN' and table_name='SILLY' and column_name='
ID';

SUBSTR(DATA_TYPE,1,10)                   DATA_LENGTH DATA_SCALE DATA_PRECISION
---------------------------------------- ----------- ---------- --------------
NUMBER                                            22          0
```

What gives?

Also, I am trying to do a generic conversion from Oracle to ANSI.  Is there any way to determine from the metadata that the `NUMBER` was created as, or fits into an `INT`?

Lastly, I tried creating with `BINARY_INTEGER` which appears in the documentation, but the create statement fails:

```
SQL> create table ltheisen.silly ( id binary_integer );
create table ltheisen.silly ( id binary_integer )
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

What am I missing?

-------------------- UPDATE -----------------------------

Reading a little deeper gives this gem:

> Specify a floating-point number using the following form:
>
> **NUMBER**
>
> ```
> The absence of precision and scale designators specifies the maximum range and precision 
> for an Oracle number.
> ```

So since the datatype is NUMBER and there is no precision specified, we can assume it is maximum precision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `DATA_LENGTH` of 22 is just the largest number of bytes it can take to store the largest possible number (Oracle uses 2 digits per byte). A `NULL` `DATA_PRECISION` implies the maximum of 38.

You can verify this with `DBMS_METADATA`:

```
SQL>  create table sotmp ( a int );

Table created.

SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','SOTMP')
  2  from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','SOTMP')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "PHIL"."SOTMP"
   (    "A" NUMBER(*,0)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFER

SQL>
```

(The "*" in the above output denotes the maximum precision).

`BINARY_INTEGER` is not a data type that can be used in table columns. It can only be used as a PL/SQL variable datatype.